# How to write an SFML shader

Tags: shader, sfml

I want to start writing some shaders in SFML, but I don't know anything about writing shaders.
I've heard about GLSL but I don't know anything about it.
Also I don't really know what to search about because I don't know if anything is compatible, and even if GLSL is used in sfml for writing shaders.

So my question is what do I need to know to write some shaders for an SFML project.
By the way I am not looking for an answer saying that I should look in more detail I just want some basics on shader writing as I know completely nothing.

Comment: Since SFML is using OpenGL, you need to write your shaders in GLSL (as you stated). You can read a bit about using them in the [official documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-shader.php). For learning GLSL, there are a lot of tutorials out there to get into it. You can just google something like "GLSL tutorial" and something will come up.

Comment: @MaxPlay Thank you, I didn't know if everything was compatible with one another. I'll have a look at GLSL now

Comment: SFML actually does not care about the GLSL used afaik, because you always just access the OpenGL "below" and that version should always be the newest that you graphics card supports (if I am not mistaken). So you should be fine.